# ember.js: Make AdminRouteMixin from AuthenticatedRouteMixin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Is there a more elegant way to prevent unauthorized access to an admin-only route than writing this in all of my admin routes?

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  beforeModel: function(){
    if(!this.get('session.secure.admin')) this.transitionTo("dashboard");
  }
});
```

Perhaps it's possible to extend `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` itself to make this kind of check?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just make the mixin?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'wherever/it/is'.

const { Mixin } = Ember;

export default Mixin.create(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  beforeModel(){
    if(!this.get('session.secure.admin')) {
      this.transitionTo("dashboard");
    }
  }
})
```

And then import it in your routes:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AdminCheckMixin from 'yourApp/mixins/routes/admin-check';

const { Route } = Ember;

export default Route.extend(AdminCheckMixin);
```

Comment: *Why not just make the mixin?*  
Because I started Ember yesterday and it's a lot to take in!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JordanArseno Sorry assumed that you knew that from the title of your question, join us on the [ember community slack](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: It seems to work, but, is `Mixin.create(target, extensionObj)` really a thing tho? See [official docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html#method_create)